# How to dump the context in the templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

How can I print all the keys in the context? For example I have a view like this:

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', context={ 'first_name': 'Umut', 'last_name': 'Coşkun' })
```

How can I print all the context in the template? I'm searching for something like:

```
{{ all_the_context }}
```

And it will print:

```
{
    "first_name": "Umut",
    "last_name": "Coşkun"
}
```

Or if its an object instead of JSON, it's also okay.

Answer (score 0):

Write in your views.py.

```
def home(request):
        cont={ 'first_name': 'Umut', 'last_name': 'Coşkun' }    
        return render(request, 'home.html',context={'cont':cont})
```

and in template just use

```
{{cont}}
```

Comment: Yes It's a work around, but I'm not looking for this.

Comment: So, can you please explain your requirement.

Comment: Accessing context without make a change in the views.py